# CSS фреймворки а-ля bootstrap

Tags: фреймворк, bootstrap, css

Есть ли ещё какие-либо достойные варианты, кроме поднадоевшего bootstrap'а, и zurb foundation?

Comment: jquery ui???

Comment: кстате, вот сравнение популярных фреймворков: [http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php)

Comment: @danpetruk jQuery UI - написан на JS, он не есть CSS фреймворк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Честно, bootstrap и foundation - лучшие фреймворки для адаптивного дизайна, оба варианта прекрасно справляются с задачами для которых предназначены, только для первого больше различных дополнений как [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) например и т.п. из того, что не назвали есть ещё [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

Comment: Кендо немного не то... Ну чтож, буду юзать Foundation

Comment: >Да мне не гриды надо, а скорее кнопочки да менюшки =(

можете погуглить - для bootstrapа огромное кол-во тем и различных елементов

Answer (score 3):

С [блюпринт](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) сталкивались?
[Пример](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html).
О каких-либо плюсах или минусах не хочу говорить - практически все есть одно и то же.

Comment: Да мне не гриды надо, а скорее кнопочки да менюшки =(

Comment: @Андрей_Викторов Там же много всего,смотрите внимательней

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap в стиле google](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149373/)

Comment: Но, при этом всёравно бутстрап

Comment: @Андрей Викторов Ну это зависит от того, что принимать под смыслом слова "бутстрап" :)

Answer (score 1):

[`Fbootstrapp`](http://ckrack.github.com/fbootstrapp/) - похожее, но не `bootstrap`.

> Fbootstrapp is a toolkit designed to kickstart development of facebook iframe apps in both relevant sizes. It includes base CSS and HTML for typography, forms, buttons, tables, grids, navigation, and more, styled in the typical facebook look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap включает в себя несколько вещей. Если я правильно понял, вы спрашиваете про модульные сетки и адаптивный дизайн.

Для CSS Bootstrap буквально лучшее решение. Но он упирается в ограничения языка - если вы хотите более удобные инструменты, понадобится использовать SCSS/Stylus/PostCSS.

В качестве самого grid-фреймворка есть очень продуманная библиотека [Jeet](http://jeet.gs/). Для упрощения других задач существует еще множество библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

**Uikit** - Фреймворк сделан с использованием less и примесей. В случае UIKit ядро полностью отделено от стилей «шаблона». Удобные переменные позволят начинающим быстро сориентироваться и подогнать внешний вид под себя. Кто плохо ориентируется в less или не ориентируется вообще — есть удобный базовый визуальный редактор стилей, позволяющий получить вполне приемлемый результат — getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html

В сравнении с другими фреймворками:

**CSS
Без иконок**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**С иконками**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**JS**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И все вместе**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ссылки:**

[yootheme.com](http://yootheme.com) — сайт разработчиков

[getuikit.com](http://getuikit.com) — сайт UIKit

[getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html](http://getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html) — кастомайзерUIKit

[pagekit.com](http://pagekit.com) — сайт PageKit

[usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html) — список css/js фреймворков

Answer (score 0):

в последних проектах использовал [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/) хорошая альтернатива bootstrap.